# Everytime i change the image img is resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the img tag stricted. In my example, everytime i change the image, size of it also changes.

Here is an example:
[image]

```css
.cat {
 width:200px
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cat">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/400" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not match the CSS: You have height of auto so the height will adjust

Comment: do you have any idea how should i do that? When i adjust the height, its ratio changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doing `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` which is letting it go to its default size if you want to make them the same size do the same width as the cat and the same width as the img:

```
.cat {
 width:200px;
height:200px;
}
img {
 width:200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

And at that point you don't need the `.cat` because they are the same now so:

```
img {
 width:200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

You can remove the div with the class `cat` now since it's not needed.
And here's the finished code:

```css
img {
 width:200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/400" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works well, thank you. But in addition, we should use object-fit: cover; to prevent changing w-h ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Using `max-width: 100%;` means whatever size the image will be, the image will appear in it. When `width: 200px` is there, an image of any size will show in 200px only.

```
.cat 
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
img 
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images have `width` and `height` different by default. So you should specified values of them. e.g:

```css
.cat {
 width:200px;
 height: 500px;
 border: solid;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.item {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cat">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/400" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```